# How to compile and run the code written in a text editor?

Tags: ide, notepad++, sublimetext2, atom-editor, text-editor

I am new to programming, last few months since I started coding I used Jetbrains Clion IDE for writing and compiling the C code, but now I started using Sublime Text but I can't figure out how to compile and run the code.

I tried gcc compiler but it generates a 'object' file and nothing else.

Comment: If you're writing single file programs, Sublime's `C++ Single File` build system has a `Run` variant that will compile and run your code in one shot (despite the name it works for C as well). For anything more complex you would need something more, though. As a C developer it's a good idea to learn the ins and outs of compiling and linking, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to having executable code. You have successfully compiled your code to an object file. What you need to do next is **link** your object files together into an executable. To link object files into a single executable with gcc, use this following command.

`gcc -o myprogram file1.o <...other object files>`

You could then run it from a command line (not sure what OS and Shell you are using, so I imagine this step could slightly vary) by navigating to the same directory as the outputted file and running `./myprogram`.